# Removing items while iterating from a SortedDictionary in C++

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I want to remove items from a SortedDictionary while iterating if a condition satisfies. It’s crashing after removing the first item. What can be the problem in below code snippet?

```
   //SortedDictionary<String^, Status^> deviceStatus
    // deviceStatus already has some data

for each(KeyValuePair<String^, Status^> kvp in deviceStatus)
 {
     if (kvp.Value.connected ==false)
        deviceStatus.Remove(kvp.Key);
 }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged c++?

Comment: You should provide information on the error you are getting.

Comment: You cannot modify collection while iterating using `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: It should be visual c++

Comment: @orhtej2 is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @MFnx Error says “Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated”